# Get full label name of ChoiceField in QuerySet values list

Tags: python, django

I have a model with a ChoiceField, and I'm doing getting a QuerySet as values, i.e.:

```
list = Model.objects.filter(a='1').values('id','a','choicefield')
```

In this case the value of choicefield would be returned as whatever is stored in the DB. If I were getting the model returned I could do list.0.get_choicefield_display to get the full label value. There doesn't seem to be any way to get the value though when I use a values list. I've tried changing out the variable name on the values list with a get_x_display version but that doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use `only()` instead of `values()`. Like `values`, `only` retrieves a subset of the database columns. The difference is that it creates model instance objects, which means that you can use `get_X_display()` as usual.

```
instances = MyModel.objects.filter(a='1').only('id', 'a', 'choicefield')
instances[0].get_choicefield_display()  # will work fine
```

Of course, you should check out the [caveats in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#defer) on `only()` and `defer()`, but for the purposes you've described I don't see a problem.

If you want to use `values()` there are many ways to solve this problem. One approach is to define the mapping explicitly in your model:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class MyModel(models.Model):
    CHOICES_DICT = OrderedDict((
        (1, 'Choice 1'),
        (2, 'Choice 2'),
    ))
    choicefield = models.IntegerField(choices=CHOICES_DICT.items())
    ...
```

Now you can explicitly look up up the string value in your view:

```
values = MyModel.objects.filter(a='1').values('id','a','choicefield')
name = MyModel.CHOICES_DICT[values[0]['choicefield']]
```

You could also create a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) to do the same thing at the template level.

Comment: if we want to be more in the spirit of DJango, we would better do `fields = MyModel.objects.filter(id=1).first().values('choicefield')`. And if `id` is the primary key we would even better do a get, instead of a filter: `MyModel.objects.get(pk=1).choicefield`. Am I wrong?

Comment: So, if I'm doing this for a large valuequeryset/dict, I'd need to iterate through the list setting the name value for each item?

Comment: @Programming123: Yes. If you're looping in the template you could turn this into a custom filter to avoid preprocessing the list in your view. Another option would be to use `only()` instead of `values()`, which will give you instances you can use `get_choicefield_display()` on. The docs try to warn you against this, though...

Comment: @Mihai: I think you've missed the point of the question. The OP is asking specifically about using `values()` rather than getting an instance. So `get()` is out, and `values()` is a queryset method so your first example will raise an exception. Most likely the OP will be looping over the result of a `filter` call, I was just grabbing the first one for the sake of the example.

Comment: Sooo...any other ideas then? I was mostly using values to make the queries a bit faster since these queries generate anywhere from 10 to 20k rows (depending on the filters being applied). Values seemed to really speed it up.

Comment: @Programming123: All three of these ideas (looping in the view code, making a custom filter, using `only()`) get only a subset of the columns from the database. In what way do these not meet your needs?

Comment: Well, I was under the impression that values() was easier on the db than anything else, so I thought perhaps there was a clear way to get the value returned while using values. Since it's not the case I'm going to try out only() or looping through it - just looping through it seems like it would negate any advantage from .values() And, with regards to a custom filter, I'd need to define the list of values in the filter right? Just trying to limit how many places it is defined. I'll be trying this out tonight

Comment: @Programming123: I think `only()` will be the easiest way, and I've updated the question with a little more detail. As for looping, note that looping over something in Python will have *very* different performance characteristics from fetching extra data from the database, so I definitely wouldn't assume that that would negate the advantage of using `values()`. (That said, looping isn't necessary.)